# Checkstyle config file from dependency jar

Tags: gradle, dependencies, checkstyle

I am trying to apply the checkstyle plugin to my gradle project. The configuration of which is in a seperate, shared jar dependency:

```java
project.apply plugin: StaticAnalysisPlugin

class StaticAnalysisPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.apply plugin: 'checkstyle'     

        project.configurations {
            codingStandardsConfig
        }

        project.dependencies {
            codingStandardsConfig 'com.sample.tools:coding-standards:1.+:@jar'
        }

        def checkstyleConfigFileLocation = "classpath:sample-checkstyle-config.xml"

        project.checkstyle {
            toolVersion = '6.3'
            project.logger.debug "$project Using checkstyle version $toolVersion."
            project.logger.debug "$project Using checkstyle config from: ${checkstyleConfigFileLocation}"
            config = project.resources.text.fromFile(checkstyleConfigFileLocation)
        }

        project.checkstyleMain.source = "src/main/java"
        project.checkstyleTest.exclude "**/*"
    }
}
```

the config file is located in the coding-standards jar, but I am unsure how to wire this in to the checkstyle config.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `configFile` option (which expects a `File` object) rather than the `config` option (which expects a text resource with your actual configuration).

Then the problem comes down to determining the correct `File` object. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962028/1005481), it seems you can do

```java
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("file/test.xml").getFile());
```

[Alternative solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+[jar]+read+file+from+jar) can be found on StackOverflow. Make sure that the class loader's class path includes your coding-standards.jar. You may have to put that dependency in a `buildscript` block to make it available, well, to the build script.